# Prevent customers from ordering from more than 3 Vendors in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, cart, product, hook-woocommerce

I have found similar solutions to this, for example: "How to limit orders to one category". I have tried to modify the code but it's not specific enough.

In my case, each Vendor is defined by a product attribute value, 8 Terms at all. If the cart contains products from more than 3 different Terms, I need to set up a message that says "Sorry, you may only order from 3 different Vendors at a time".

This is what I'm using as a starting point:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'three_vendors' );
function three_vendors() {

  if ATTRIBUTE = SELECT A VENDOR; NUMBER OF TERMS > 3 {

   echo "Sorry! You can only order from 3 Vendors at a time.”;

   }
}
```

The middle line is me filling in the blanks using non-php language.

I am looking for a way to define the amount of variations in the cart. If this is not possible to do with Attributes, I am open to use Categories instead.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Update:** Is not possible to manage variations with **`woocommerce_add_to_cart_valisation`** hook

Instead we can use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_add_to_cart`** filter hook, removing the last added cart item when more than 3 vendors (items) are in cart:

```
// Remove the cart item and display a notice when more than 3 values for "pa_vendor" attibute.
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'no_more_than_three_vendors', 10, 6 );

function no_more_than_three_vendors( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {

    // Check only when there is more than 3 cart items
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() < 4 ) return;

    // SET BELOW your attribute slug… always begins by "pa_"
    $attribute_slug = 'pa_vendor'; // (like for "Color" attribute the slug is "pa_color")

    // The current product object
    $product = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
    // the current attribute value of the product
    $curr_attr_value = $product->get_attribute( $attribute_slug );

    // We store that value in an indexed array (as key /value)
    $attribute_values[ $curr_attr_value ] = $curr_attr_value;

    //Iterating through each cart item
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        // The attribute value for the current cart item
        $attr_value = $cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_attribute( $attribute_slug );

        // We store the values in an array: Each different value will be stored only one time
        $attribute_values[ $attr_value ] = $attr_value;
    }
    // We count the "different" values stored
    $count = count($attribute_values);

    // if there is more than 3 different values
    if( $count > 3 ){
        // We remove last cart item
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
        // We display an error message
        wc_clear_notices();
        wc_add_notice( __( "Sorry, you may only order from 3 different Vendors at a time. This item has been removed", "woocommerce" ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and should works for you. It will check for the attribute values regarding your specific attribute and will remove last added cart item  for more than 3 attribute values.

> The only annoying thing is that I can't remove the classic added to cart notice for the moment. **I will try to find another way…**

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I'm looking for.

It looks right but it's buggy on the site. For example, when my basket is empty and I try to add a product, I receive an error message that says the website cannot handle the request right now. When I disable the snippet and then add to cart it works fine. When I activate the snippet again and add an item from a third Vendor I see the popup message that says "Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination."

Any idea why it is doing this?

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec

A quick update - I am no longer receiving the "Sorry no products..." popup. When my cart is empty I still receive the "website cannot handle request" error message. When I deactivate the PHP, add a product, and then reactivate the code, I can add as many products as I want and nothing happens. I have reviewed the code you sent me thoroughly and it seems solid. Could the problem be elsewhere on the site?

Comment: @CraigdeGouveia I have found another way to do it … see my updated answer… Thanks.

Comment: Excellent @LoisThe Aztec it's functioning perfectly! Don't worry about the "Added to cart" notice as I'm using a custom shop page where this is not visible. The wc_add_notice message doesn't show up though, is there a different format that could work for this notification?